# How can I apply auto-levels to a series of photographs, with each photo considered separately?

Tags: photoshop, batch, levels

I'm working on a set of photos that I want to enhance automatically. I used an action that I created by my self using the levels option of PS. Yet every single photo has its own histogram so when I perform the action on a whole folder the results are not pretty much convincing.

I am wondering if there is any tool that allows you to enhance automatically a directory of photos and taking in consideration the properties of each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org)** with the `auto-level` or `level` flags.

```
convert input.jpg -auto-level output.jpg
convert input.jpg -level 1%,99% output.jpg
```

On **Linux** or **Mac**, you can use a `bash` control structure to perform the operation on multiple image files.

```
for f in *.jpg ; do
   convert "$f" -level 1%,99% "${f%.jpg}-level.jpg"
done
```

For **Windows**, you can install a `bash` shell, like [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) or Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Anyone who knows the native `cmd` or PowerShell commands for Windows, feel free to edit to add.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the first command line it works perfectly yet the bash script doesn't work it gives this error : ' ./enhance_photos
./enhance_photos: line 1: {rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1504cocoasubrtf830: command not found
./enhance_photos: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./enhance_photos: line 2: `{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 HelveticaNeue;}' '

Comment: It looks like you typed the script in a word processor (references to rtf).  You need to use a text editor.  Not familiar enough with Mac to know what editor to use.

Comment: Yes you're right. I may use atom and see if ti's going to work. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I used atom and the bash script is executed. Yet it gives me this error : convert: unable to open image '*.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3489.
convert: no images defined `*-level.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3288. I execute the bash script this way : ./enhance_photos. If you have an idea why it doesn't recognize the photos inside the folder, it would be great.